# Advice on Affiliate Programs for Music for Android app

Tags: android, affiliate

I'm looking for advice and your preferences on different music affiliate services for use in my Android application.  My end goal is to have a revenue stream via dynamic affiliate links to any artist's music. The music should be purchasable via the web browser (not in app)

The two affiliate programs that I'm most aware of are Amazon and iTunes. Here are my issues:

1. Amazon seems to have a grudge against mobile apps and its in their TOS that the affiliate program cannot be used. Not really sure why, but its stopping me from using them.
2. iTunes is a Apple thing and it goes against my moral code to have them in an Android app, not to mention my users wouldn't even be able to buy music via their Android phone.

Have you used any other services with success? Should I bother contacting Amazon to ask for permission to use their associates program on a mobile app?

Moderators: If this belongs somewhere else on the stack exchange network, please let me know and I'll move it.

Comment: any update for this question? actually i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in certain countries there is http://www.7digital.com/affiliates

Also, there is eMusic which is a little different as it's a subscription: http://www.emusic.com/affiliate/partner.html

Comment: The emusic affiliate like is currently down. Have you had any personal experience with 7digital?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I just googled it and found them. I have bought tracks from 7Digital and they've been cool :)