# Android music affiliate / associate programs

Tags: java, android, mobile, mp3, affiliate

I have developed a music app for Android.  At one stage in the application, the users can click on a song that they liked (when it was playing) and I'd like to be able to direct them to download it.  This should preferably generate revenue as an affiliate purchase however I can't find a company which offers this service.  I know Amazon has a product API but it seems they forbid using it in mobile applications.  I saw this thread and it didn't give any useful information:

[Advice on Affiliate Programs for Music for Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709857/advice-on-affiliate-programs-for-music-for-android-app)

Has anyone used a web service to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try http://www.barnesandnoble.com/affiliate/index.asp ? They seem pretty open by reading the FAQ. Note that I have no experience dealing with it.

There's also [Best Buy affiliate progam](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/regularCat%3Apcmcat198500050002/regularCat%3Apcmcat198500050002/pcmcat198500050002.c?id=pcmcat198500050002&searchresults=1&searchterm=affiliate).

And, finally, how can we forget about [Walmart](http://mp3.walmart.com/store/help/affiliateprogramFAQ.htm)?